# Sharepoint ListAdded event

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to execute some code when a new document library is added.I have created an event receiver for Lists and handle the ListAdded event.The error i get after debug/deploy is
"The object cannot be created from sandboxed code assembly...

Comment: I suggest your event handler code

Answer (score 0):

To cause the event to trigger on all sites in the site collection, the scope of the Feature must be changed to Site; this way, the functionality is enabled when we activate the Feature at the site collection rather than having to activate the Feature on every subsite. Note that the Site scope of a Feature refers to site collection (see Figure 7); Web scope refers to the sites.

[image]

more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg981880.aspx